# MySQL large table performance optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause

I'm trying to solve performance issue with this table

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| direction_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rate         | decimal(16,6)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

which contains about 100M rows

There is only one query selects data from this table:

```
SELECT AVG(rate) AS rate, created_at 
FROM statistics 
WHERE direction_id = ? 
AND created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY created_at
```

`direction_id` is a foreign key but it has quite poor selectivity:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys                   | key                             | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | statistics | NULL       | ref  | statistics_direction_id_foreign | statistics_direction_id_foreign | 4       | const | 26254 |    11.11 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I'm looking for a way to solve this problem and need for advice.
Does partitioning by HASH(direction_id) help me or not?
If it helps what is the best way to do this?

Or maybe there is some another way to fix it.

Comment: `YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), DAY(created_at)` Eh?

Comment: @Strawberry it doesn't matter, I think it could be omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the average daily rates, you meant this?

```
SELECT AVG(rate) AS rate, 
       DATE(created_at) 
    FROM statistics 
    WHERE direction_id = ? 
      AND created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? 
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

And have `INDEX(direction_id, created, rate)` -- it is both "covering" and "composite".  The explain will say "Using index" to indicate "covering", which indicates the the entire query can be performed looking only at the index's BTree.  Hence, "Covering" gives an extra performance boost.

Changing to a fancy index involving `DATE(created_at)` probably won't help *in this query*.

`PARTITIONing` is *not* indicated.

"Summary tables" may be indicated.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: I decided to reduce amount of data for each `direction_id`. I think that's the only way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix your query so it is a valid aggregation query. Presumably, you want a daily average of `rate`, so:

```
SELECT AVG(rate) AS rate, DATE(created_at) as created_day
FROM statistics 
WHERE direction_id = ? AND created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Then, I would recommend creating the following index:

```
create index idx_statistics on statistics (direction_id, created_at, rate);
```

In recent versions of MySQL, we could also consider using an index on `date(create_at)`. If you can live with the following `where` clause:

```
WHERE direction_id = ? AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Then the following index would come handy:

```
create index idx_statistics on statistics (direction_id, (date(created_at)), rate);
```

Comment: is it necessary to include `rate` to index?

Comment: Specifically, MySQL 8.0.13 is the first version that supports expression indexes.

Comment: seems that it has no effect. Index is used but there are still 26200 rows

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko: I am unsure about your comment. The index is there to improve performance, not to change the number of rows that the query returns.

Comment: The index is called "covering" because it includes _all_ the columns needed anywhere in the query.  The explain will indicate this by saving "Using index" (which is not the same as "Using index condition").